# Custom map for base class' property using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have the following models:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public class Child1 : BaseEntity { }

public class Child2 : BaseEntity { }
```

Dates are written into my database in UTC, but when I pull them out into viewmodels, I want the dates to be displayed in local time.  So this is what I tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseEntity, BaseViewModel>()
    .ForMember(e => e.CreatedDate, b => b.MapFrom(x => DateHelper.ConvertToLocalTimeZone(x.CreatedDate)))
    .ForMember(e => e.ModifiedDate, b => b.MapFrom(x => DateHelper.ConvertToLocalTimeZone(x.ModifiedDate)));
```

This does not work.  It only works when I create the map explicitly for the child classes, like this, which I hardly think is reasonable to have to do:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Child1, Child1ViewModel>()
    .ForMember(e => e.CreatedDate, b => b.MapFrom(x => DateHelper.ConvertToLocalTimeZone(x.CreatedDate)))
    .ForMember(e => e.ModifiedDate, b => b.MapFrom(x => DateHelper.ConvertToLocalTimeZone(x.ModifiedDate)));
```

I did some searching, but didn't find a solution that seemed to handle the custom mapping at the base class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Display logic like this should be done in your views, not in your view models. Keep your view models as DateTime, and then depending on your view technology you can create templated helpers or HtmlHelper extensions to standardize on how dates are displayed.

Comment: That's fair.  I'll see if I can just pass UTC time all the way to my front-end and have momentjs display local time.  I'd still like to know how to solve this mapping issue, though.

Comment: How are you passing the model to the UI? Are you using Razor or AJAX?

Comment: I'm getting it from a .NET Web API into my AngularJS front-end.  I'm wrapping up creating a custom utc-to-local filter :P.

Comment: Ah, perfect, you can plug straight in to JSON serialization then, formatting the dates appropriately through there.